# How can I get the current user executing a Laravel Command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to build a custom configuration that gets added to my Laravel configuration at boot up. I created an artisan command that allows the developers to place the server into 'test' mode and 'live' mode. This should then force API's to use test keys rather than live keys which works fine.

```
public function handle()
{
    switch(strtoupper($this->argument('m'))) {
        case 'LIVE':
            \DB::table('server_mode')->where('id', 1)->update([
                'mode' => true,
                'verified_by' => 'Server'
            ]);
            $this->info('Server is now in LIVE mode');
            break;
        case 'TEST':
            \DB::table('server_mode')->where('id', 1)->update([
                'mode' => false,
                'verified_by' => 'Server'
            ]);
            $this->info('Server is now in TEST mode');
            break;
        default:
            $this->error('Please enter either LIVE or TEST');
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to add which developer changed the status. So far, it is hard coded to 'Server'. Is it possible to get the IP or PC information who'm executed the command to store in the DB?

Comment: Maybe your command can ask for email/password and use the standard authentication (Auth::attempt). If you're using Oauth, pass the access token as parameter to your command.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Does PHP not inherit and DOS commands when executing in MS-DOS environments that I could use to even get the local machines username? This isn't made for authentication, I would just like to keep track of who is changing the server status. Or would it be easier to just track with a 'reason' rather than trying to check who did it? @SystemGlitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As said in the comments, Jaquarh doesn't try to authenticate. He just wants to get the username of the perso who ran the command.*

You can use `$processUser = exec('whoami');` to get the current user name. (It won't work on windows)

However, be careful, usernames are not always very informative. My laptop at work came preinstalled with a user name "User".

Another idea that I can suggest is to force a "name" parameter when using your command.

Comment: That is perfect! I have tested all the PC's have unique names, IE: Workstation-1, Workstation-2 so there shouldn't be a collision using this solution! Thank-you so much. If I was to use `Auth::attempt` as you mentioned, would I just pass in the email and password into the command, like `Auth::attempt($this->ask('Email:'), $this->secret('Password:'))` ? Because I thought, If someone is using SSH then, the PC name will not show as the remote host, only the workstation they're connected to.

Comment: @Jaquarh That is correct. But using the Laravel authenticator means that you rely on the database which is probably different for every developer.

Comment: I would never recommend that you run exec().  in fact, isn't it off by default for PHP

Comment: @bretterer I don't see any problem using `exec()`. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: @SystemGlitch https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/  There is no good way to do that AFAIK through commands.  Ask for username, but they can lie. require auth may be the best way, but then you need to make sure the ask for PW is hidden.

Comment: So after reviewing my options, mainly due to SSH capability, I went with the `\Auth::attempt()`. I changed it so the developer can pass in options rather than arguments. `--test` or `--live`, or none will dispute the current mode opposite. Before the 'change' happens, they had to authenticate themselves. I used my RBAC to achieve this with more security since `attempt()` accepts an array of `column => value`. Thanks for the help!